# Unable to install Detox on React Native 0.57.7

Tags: react-native, detox

I am trying to add detox to my React Native app. When I run the command:

```
yarn add detox --dev
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: Command failed: 
/Users/praveen/Documents/coding/react/BarsAppAmplify/node_modules/detox/scripts/build_framework.ios.sh
    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:611:11)
    at Object.execFileSync (child_process.js:629:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/praveen/Documents/coding/react/BarsAppAmplify/node_modules/detox/scripts/postinstall.js:2:27)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:688:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
```

Is there a solution to this? Regards.